# Select date in two table with all null value

Tags: sql-server

I Have 2 Table in SQL SERVER 2005:

firts table :

```
Tanggal
2015/01/01
2015/01/02
2015/01/03
2015/01/04
2015/01/05
2015/01/06
```

Second Table :

```
Tanggal           Jam_Masuk               Jam_Pulang
2015/01/01        08:00:00                17:00:00          
2015/01/03        08:00:00                17:00:00     
2015/01/05        08:00:00                17:00:00    
2015/01/06        08:00:00                17:00:00
```

I want select like this :

```
Tanggal           Jam_Masuk               Jam_Pulang             Total           Status
2015/01/01        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK         
2015/01/02        --:--:--                --:--:--               --:--:--        ALPHA/IZIN         
2015/01/03        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK         
2015/01/04        --:--:--                --:--:--               --:--:--        ALPHA/IZIN         
2015/01/05        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK         
2015/01/06        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK
```

Note : Field Total (hh:mm:ss)= Jam_Pulang - Jam_Masuk

I use this query :

```
SELECT t1.Tanggal,
       t2.Jam_Masuk,
       t2.Jam_Pulang,
       Datepart(hh, Cast(t2.Jam_Pulang AS TIME)) - Datepart(hh, Cast(t2.Jam_Masuk AS TIME)) AS Total,
       CASE
         WHEN Jam_Masuk IS NULL
              AND Jam_Pulang IS NULL THEN  'ALPHA/IZIN'
         ELSE 'ok'
       END [status]
FROM   firts_table t1
       LEFT JOIN second_table t2
              ON t1.Tanggal = t2.Tanggal 
where t2.id_user = '00600320'
order by t2.tanggal asc
```

1. why ? tanggal 2015/11/02 and 2015/11/04 not include
2. time only hh not with hh:mm:ss

Please Help me
Thanks Before

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: Would be much easier if you try to explain what are you trying to get and not only the plain result expected

Comment: please format the question. Also where are the dates '2015/11/02' and '2015/11/04' in the table?

Comment: Where is t2. id_user = '00600320' in Your 2nd table? How You are Mentioning That Filter Condition in Your Query? and where are 2015/11/02 and 2015/11/04 these dates in table? How You are asking these Dates Not included?

Comment: what is the datatype of columns Jam_Pulang and Jam_Masuk ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the where clause: you didn't give us info on that part and that most probably is the wrong one!

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/406835

```
CREATE TABLE #Tangga1(  [Tangga1] [date] NOT NULL );
CREATE TABLE #Tangga2( [Tangga1] [date] NOT NULL, [Jam_Masuk] [datetime] NOT NULL, [Jam_Pulang] [datetime] NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #Tangga1
SELECT '2015-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-01-02'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-01-03'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-01-04'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-01-05'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-01-06'

INSERT INTO #Tangga2
SELECT '2015-01-01', '2015-01-01 08:00:00.000', '2015-01-01 17:00:00.000'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-01-03', '2015-01-01 08:00:00.000', '2015-01-01 17:00:00.000'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-01-05', '2015-01-01 08:00:00.000', '2015-01-01 17:00:00.000'
UNION ALL SELECT '2015-01-06', '2015-01-01 08:00:00.000', '2015-01-01 17:00:00.000'

SELECT t1.Tangga1, t2.Jam_Masuk, t2.Jam_Pulang, Datepart(hh, Cast(t2.Jam_Pulang AS TIME)) - Datepart(hh, Cast(t2.Jam_Masuk AS TIME)) AS Total,
       CASE
         WHEN Jam_Masuk IS NULL
              AND Jam_Pulang IS NULL THEN  'ALPHA/IZIN'
         ELSE 'ok'
       END [status]
FROM   #tangga1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN #tangga2 t2
              ON t1.Tangga1 = t2.Tangga1

DROP TABLE #Tangga1
DROP TABLE #Tangga2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For your First question,

   Assuming that you were asked why '`2015/01/02`' and '`2015/01/04`' date's data's are not included. not `'2015/11/02'` and `'2015/11/04'`. This Reason is you are using `LEFT OUT JOIN` in your query. It will return all common records between the two `tables` also the records present only in `left table`. since `'2015/01/02'` and `'2015/01/04'` dates not present in `second table` obviously there will not be any `data` for these `dates`.
2. For 2nd question, You require hour only not hh:mm:ss. Try below query,

   ```
      SELECT  t1.Tanggal,
      t 2.Jam_Masuk,
      t2.Jam_Pulang,
      datediff(hour, t2.Jam_Pulang , t2.Jam_Masuk) AS Total,
      CASE
        WHEN Jam_Masuk IS NULL
             AND Jam_Pulang IS NULL THEN  'ALPHA/IZIN'
        ELSE 'ok'
      END [status]
      FROM   firts_table t1
      LEFT JOIN second_table t2
             ON t1.Tanggal = t2.Tanggal

      order by t2.tanggal asc
   ```

(Assumes that  `Jam_Pulang` and `Jam_Masuk` columns have `datetime` datatype)